Cannot Build APK in Flutter Project - Error: Execution failed for task ':connectivity:verifyReleaseResources'
I’m working on a Flutter project, and I’m encountering the following error when trying to build an APK:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR: /Users/***/Projects/***/build/connectivity/intermediates/merged_res/release/values/values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

\[✓\] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on macOS 14.7.1 23H222 darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR)
• Flutter version 3.24.4 on channel stable at /Users/\*\*\*/Development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 603104015d (6 weeks ago), 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
• Engine revision db49896cf2
• Dart version 3.5.4
• DevTools version 2.37.3

\[✓\] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/\*\*\*/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
• All Android licenses accepted.

\[✓\] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 16B40
• CocoaPods version 1.16.2

\[✓\] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

\[✓\] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

\[✓\] VS Code (version 1.95.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.102.0

I tried upgrading the Flutter SDK to the latest version and also updated the connectivity package in pubspec.yaml. Additionally, I cleaned the project using flutter clean and rebuilt it, but the error persisted. I expected the build process to complete successfully and generate an APK, but it failed with the same error.

Can you execute this in your terminal: cd android and ./gradlew assembleDebug --info if for debug, ./gradlew assembleRelease --info if for release? Let me know what output it generates.
